# Sorting Array alphabetically, keeping numbers and special chars at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm sorting an Array alphabetically using this :

```
contactList.sort((function(index){
        return function(a, b){
            return (a[index] == b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
        };
    })(2));
```

It works great, the only problem is that numbers and special characters appear at the top of my array. I would like it to be sorted alphabetically, but I also want it to store the numbers & special chars at the end.

I really have no idea how to modify my function in order to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check, whether are they letters or not.
I'm checking only first character, but maybe you'll need to extend this check for case 
`a[index].charAt(0) == b[index].charAt(0)` to compare following letters and so on in loop.

```
contactList.sort((function(index){
    return function(a, b){
        var aIsLetter = a[index].charAt(0).match(/[a-z]/i),
            bIsLetter = b[index].charAt(0).match(/[a-z]/i);
        if (aIsLetter && !bIsLetter) return -1;
        if (!aIsLetter && bIsLetter) return 1;
        return (a[index] == b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
    };
})(2));
```

Comment: Works great. Although it turns out aIsLetter && !bIsLetter should return -1, and vice versa. I can't edit your code since it's less than 6 characters, so if you could edit it yourself.. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Hi, what is the use for the index parameter?seems to be redundant.    function(a, b){
                a = a.toLowerCase();
                b = b.toLowerCase();
                var aIsLetter = a.charAt(0).match(/[a-z]/i),
                    bIsLetter = b.charAt(0).match(/[a-z]/i);
                if (aIsLetter && !bIsLetter) return -1;
                if (!aIsLetter && bIsLetter) return 1;

                return (a == b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1));
            }